# How to change the time dilation using C++ in Unreal Engine?

Tags: c++, unreal-4, unreal

I searched a bit and found a blueprint solution which does this but I've just started using Unreal and I prefer C++ instead of this visual programming thingy.

I'm looking for a Unity-like `Time.timeScale` property which could be easily set during runtime.

Is there a thing like that in Unreal? 
I just want to play with changing the speed of time of the whole world.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use [`SetTimeDilation`](http://api.unrealengine.com/INT/API/Runtime/Engine/GameFramework/AWorldSettings/SetTimeDilation/index.html) on the world settings.